# Forgetful functor to the functor from the category of spaces to that of pointed spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to define a forgetful functor $\beta:\textbf{Top}^0\to \textbf{Top}$, where $\textbf{Top}^0$ is the category of pointed spaces and pointed continuous maps.

I know that $\beta$ should forget what the base point of any pointed space is. But I am not sure exactly what this means.

Is it that we simply forget that $x_X$ is the base point of the pointed space $(X,x_X)$? Or does it mean that we are actually removing $x_X$ from $X$, ie is $\beta(X,x_X)=X\setminus \{x\}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the first: the functor takes the form $\mathbf{Top}^0\to\mathbf{Top}, (X,x_X)\mapsto X$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is it possible to explain briefly why the second option is wrong, and/or why the first option is the preferred one. I am somewhat new to free and forgetful functors and I don't have an understanding of them except some simple examples.

Comment: @frelg The operation that deletes the point isn't a functor since you might have a map $(X, \{x\}) \to (Y, \{y\})$ that sends some point $z$ other than the basepoint $x$ of $X$ to the base point $y$ of $Y$, and now it's not clear where to send $z$.

Comment: @hunter I see, makes sense.

Comment: Also, would $\beta(f)$, for some $f:(X,x_0)\to (Y,y_0)$ pointed map, be just the same map $f$? Is it indeed still sending $x_0\mapsto y_0$, but we (for a lack of a better way to say it on my part) just don't care about where $x_0$ goes?

Comment: @frelg Indeed, we send $f\colon(X,x_0)\to (Y,y_0)$ to the underlying map of topological spaces $f\colon X\to Y$, and I think it is a good way of phrasing it that we just don't care anymore where $x_0$ is sent in particular.

Comment: To put this another way, what we forget is not the *existence* of the point $x_X$, but its *special nature* as the preferred base point of $X$. If we all forget about the concept of authoritarian military dictators, Julius Caesar and Napoleon Bonaparte still exist somewhere in the history of our world.

Comment: Thank you both of you :)) This is very clear to me now.